# Compare two string objects for matched string

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, object, associative-array

I was just wondering how I could search and compare two string object and check if either contains a matching string.

I have an associative array containing terms and explanations.
I also have this array broken into two objects "keys"(keys showing the key of the associative array) and "values"(values showing the value of each key in array).

I have another associative array containing a dish and its explanation.
I have split the dish's description into separate words put them into an object.

What I would like to do now is check for every word in descsplit search the TermList and return explanation of term found if found.
 eg.  free-range is contained in dish explanation, check if there is a match for free-range in TermList and return the value(explanation) of free-range.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

```
var TermList= {
'Al dente' : 'Al dente : Pasta cooked until just firm. From the Italian "to the tooth." ',
'Bake' : 'Bake: To cook food in an oven, surrounded with dry heat; called roasting when applied to meat or poultry.',
'Barbecue' : 'Barbecue: To cook foods on a rack or a spit over coals.',
'Baste' : 'Baste: To moisten food for added flavor and to prevent drying out while cooking.',
'Batter' : 'Batter: An uncooked pourable mixture usually made up of flour, a liquid, and other ingredients.',
'Beat' : 'Beat: To stir rapidly to make a mixture smooth, using a whisk, spoon, or mixer.',
'Blanch' : 'Blanch: To cook briefly in boiling water to seal in flavor and color; usually used for vegetables or fruit, to prepare for freezing, and to ease skin removal.',
'Blend' : 'Blend: To thoroughly combine 2 or more ingredients, either by hand with a whisk or spoon, or with a mixer.',
'Boil': 'Boil: To cook in bubbling water that has reached 100 degrees Celcius.',
'Bone' : 'Bone: To remove bones from poultry, meat, or fish.',
'Bouquet garni' : 'Bouquet garni: A tied bundle of herbs, usually parsley, thyme, and bay leaves, that is added to flavor soups, stews, and sauces but removed before serving.',
'Braise' : 'Braise: To cook first by browning, then gently simmering in a small amount of liquid over low heat in a covered pan until tender.',
'Bread': 'Bread: To coat with crumbs or cornmeal before cooking.',
'Free-range': 'Free-range: (Of livestock, especially poultry) kept in natural conditions, with freedom of movement/ (Of eggs) produced by free-range poultry.'
};

var values = []; // Creating an object for the values of the terms in TermList
var keys = []; // Creating an object for the keys of the terms in TermList

//function to assign the keys of terms to object keys.
function showkey() {
for (var key in TermList) {
    if (TermList.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        keys.push(key);
    }
}

//function that shows the value of each key in TermList.
function showValue(){
for( var value in TermList){
    values.push(TermList[value]);
}

showkey(); 
showValue();

var DishList={
"Chicken and Stuffing Sandwich": "Chicken and Stuffing Sandwich: Succulent Sandwich made from free-range chicken and fresh breadcrumbs mixed with mayonnaise",
"Eggs Benedict": "Poached eggs served with spinach and hollandaise sauce"
};

var descsplit = [];
function SplitDesc() {
for (var value in DishList) {
     descsplit.push(DishList[value].split(/[\s.,?!:]+/)); // Splits the values of the key up in Dishlist, and puts them into array.Also makes them avoid punctuations while splitting.
}

}
SplitDesc();

//For every word in descsplit search the TermList and return explanation of term found if found
```

Comment: Something like `if ("free-range" in TermList) { ...`

Comment: Captialisation and punctuation are important: `'Free-range' != 'free-range' != 'free range'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested fully, but this may work

```
var TermList= {
'Al dente' : 'Al dente : Pasta cooked until just firm. From the Italian "to the tooth." ',
'Bake' : 'Bake: To cook food in an oven, surrounded with dry heat; called roasting when applied to meat or poultry.',
'Barbecue' : 'Barbecue: To cook foods on a rack or a spit over coals.',
'Baste' : 'Baste: To moisten food for added flavor and to prevent drying out while cooking.',
'Batter' : 'Batter: An uncooked pourable mixture usually made up of flour, a liquid, and other ingredients.',
'Beat' : 'Beat: To stir rapidly to make a mixture smooth, using a whisk, spoon, or mixer.',
'Blanch' : 'Blanch: To cook briefly in boiling water to seal in flavor and color; usually used for vegetables or fruit, to prepare for freezing, and to ease skin removal.',
'Blend' : 'Blend: To thoroughly combine 2 or more ingredients, either by hand with a whisk or spoon, or with a mixer.',
'Boil': 'Boil: To cook in bubbling water that has reached 100 degrees Celcius.',
'Bone' : 'Bone: To remove bones from poultry, meat, or fish.',
'Bouquet garni' : 'Bouquet garni: A tied bundle of herbs, usually parsley, thyme, and bay leaves, that is added to flavor soups, stews, and sauces but removed before serving.',
'Braise' : 'Braise: To cook first by browning, then gently simmering in a small amount of liquid over low heat in a covered pan until tender.',
'Bread': 'Bread: To coat with crumbs or cornmeal before cooking.',
'Free-range': 'Free-range: (Of livestock, especially poultry) kept in natural conditions, with freedom of movement/ (Of eggs) produced by free-range poultry.'
};

var DishList={
"Chicken and Stuffing Sandwich": "Chicken and Stuffing Sandwich: Succulent Sandwich made from free-range chicken and fresh breadcrumbs mixed with mayonnaise",
"Eggs Benedict": "Poached eggs served with spinach and hollandaise sauce"
};

var keys = Object.keys(TermList);
for(var key in DishList){
  var val = DishList[key];
  for(var iIndex=0;iIndex<keys.length ;iIndex++){
    var term = keys[iIndex];
    var regx = new RegExp('\\b'+term+'\\b',"gi");
    var found = null;
        while((found = regx.exec(val))!=null){
            console.log('Found term "'+ term+ '" at index '+found.index);
        }
    }
}
```